# how to add angular tags to html attribute in jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I add  jquery datepicker to asp.net mvc5 project . but i couldn't bind angularjs object to it .

```
 @Html.JQueryUI().Datepicker("date")
```

how do i bind above controller to angularjs object

eg.

```
<input type="date" placeholder="Date" data-ng-model="returndate" />
```

Comment: What is `@Html.JQueryUI()`? (that is no part of mvc and you should at least include a link to the plugin your using)

Comment: Why do you mix jQuery with AngularJS?

Comment: actualy i want to add better date picker to my project. so i add jqueryui datepicker . is their better way to do this.

Comment: this example i use to do that. http://ilyasmamunbd.blogspot.com/2014/02/jquery-ui-datepicker-popup-calendar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do that add Jquery to my chtml code.

**CHTML**

```
 <input type="date" value="{{ date | date: 'yyyy/MM/dd' }}" placeholder="Departure Date"  data-ng-model="departuredate"/>
```

**JQUERY**

```
@section Scripts{
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#txtDepartureDate").datepicker({
            numberOfMonths: 2,
            minDate: -0,
            onSelect: function (selected) {
                var dt = new Date(selected);
                dt.setDate(dt.getDate() + 1);
                $("#txtReturnDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", dt);
            }
        });

    });

</script>}
```

Thank you, it works now!